# why is my parameter value not being passed in QueryString

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a parameter:

```
string custName = "";

custName = AddressDT.Rows[0]["first_name"].ToString() + " " + AddressDT.Rows[0]["last_name"].ToString();
```

I am performing my Response.Redirect

```
Response.Redirect("~/Account/EmailError.aspx?parm1=custName");
```

and I am retrieving the parameter value:

```
custName = Request.QueryString["parm1"];
```

when I run debug: ... custName = "custName"

what am I doing wrong? I have done this before with no issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already know that QueryString value is string, you need to use [UrlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

In addition, you want to use `String.Format` as much as possible for good design practice instead of +.

```
string custName = String.Format("{0} {1}", 
   AddressDT.Rows[0]["first_name"].ToString(), 
   AddressDT.Rows[0]["last_name"].ToString());

string url = String.Format("~/Account/EmailError.aspx?parm1={0}", 
   Server.UrlEncode(custName));

Response.Redirect(url);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `Response.Redirect` is passing the string "custName", not the value of the variable.

This will fix it for you:

```
Response.Redirect("~/Account/EmailError.aspx?param1=" + custName);
```

Comment: Also here: you should probably make sure that the value of custName is URL encoded properly.

Comment: I might be wrong, but I am fairly certain that the MVC routing engine (which is in play with `Response.Redirect()`) would take care of that automatically for you. But, it never hurts to double check yourself.

Answer (score 2):

That is because you're using a String Constant as the value for the parameter.

```
Response.Redirect("~/Account/EmailError.aspx?parm1=custName");
```

That would always cause the URL to be set with the string `custName`.

Try using the variable name as:

```
Response.Redirect("~/Account/EmailError.aspx?parm1=" + custName);
```

Now the variable would be appended to the request.

Now when you'll run the code, it would produce the value in the Variable and you'll get the code running fine.

Always remember to finish the string and then adding the variable values. Everything inside the double qoutes is considered to be a string and not a variable name or a keyword.

Comment: You should probably make sure that the value of `custName` is URL encoded properly.